# How to test your own (single image) data using an already trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, testing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run this [repository](https://github.com/ialhashim/DenseDepth). And, trying to test with my own data. While I was trying to do it, I am getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 34, in
>   
>       outputs = predict(model, inputs)   File "/home/kbdp5524/Downloads/DenseDepth-master/utils.py", line 12, in
>   predict
>       predictions = model.predict(images, batch_size=batch_size)   File "/home/kbdp5524/anaconda3/envs/densedepth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1441, in predict
>       x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)   File "/home/kbdp5524/anaconda3/envs/densedepth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 579, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='input')   File "/home/kbdp5524/anaconda3/envs/densedepth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py",
>   line 145, in standardize_input_data
>       str(data_shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape
>   (None, None, 3) but got array with shape (480, 640, 4)

This is the [test.py](https://github.com/ialhashim/DenseDepth/blob/master/test.py) and [train.py](https://github.com/ialhashim/DenseDepth/blob/master/train.py) code

Can anyone please help me through this. I am new to coding :)

Comment: You're feeding an RGBA image (4 channels), the network expects just 3. Convert the image to RGB (and make sure there are no other preprocessing operations you need to do) before feeding it to the network

Comment: Thank you :) Also, what does (None, None) mean?

Comment: `None` in a shape means any shape is allowed there. In this case, your net accepts as input images of any width/height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input image have shape (None, None, 4) a RGBA image but model want a 3 channel image mean (None, None, 3) RGB. So you have to convert yout image to 3 channel .
You can do that using OpenCV function `cv2.cvtColor(Image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB )`.

To install openCV : pip install python-opencv